# When did Jeor Mormont ask Tarly to send the ravens?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the first episode of the third season of *Game of Thrones* we can see Jeor Mormont burning a wight. After that Jeor asks Sam:

> Did you send the raven Tarly? Did you send the raven? That was the
>   only thing you were supposed to do.

When in the previous episodes (Season 2) did Jeor ask Sam to send the ravens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't shown on screen.

Sam was supposed to do that during the [Battle of the Fist of the First Men](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Fist_of_the_First_Men), but since the battle was not shown in the TV show we don't know what was happening to him during it and under what circumstances he failed this task.

This is in contrast to the [events from the book](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Differences_between_books_and_TV_series_-_Season_3#Valar_Dohaeris):

> Samwell Tarly is on the Fist of the First Men during the White
>   Walker/wight attack. He did send out ravens, but only two of them
>   carried a message.